# Does altering the display property of a list item cause it to lose its semantic meaning?

Tags: html, css

As outlined in the [this](https://www.tpgi.com/short-note-on-what-css-display-properties-do-to-table-semantics/#:%7E:text=The%20CSS%20display%20properties%20are,in%20the%20browser%20accessibility%20tree.) article:

> When CSS display:block or display:grid or display:flex is set on the table element, bad things happen. The table is no longer represented as a table in the accessibility tree, row elements/semantics are no longer represented in any form.

Here is the image he showed of the accessibility tree from when the default display property is used on a table:

[image: Table with default display property]

Here is the image he showed of the accessibility tree from when another value for the display property is used on a table:

[image]

My question is if this also applies to the `<li>` element as its default display property is `list-item`.

E.g. will the following inline list be semantically incorrect?

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="example.com">example 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="example.com">example 2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="example.com">example 3</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A lot of work has gone on in recent years to address this. For example, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1005271 - so I wouldn't even assume it's true for tables now just because it was in 2018, let alone for lists.

Comment: @Alohci Interesting, though I'll just use display flex on the ul element instead as that does not have its own display value (just to be safe)